# set scale in pixels in After Effects using Expressions

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

You can right click on a scale, hit Edit, and then enter scale in Pixels, inches , % of Comp, of source....

I would like to set the scale in pixels. How can set the units using expressions?

I tried returning `["200px","200px"]`, but that is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size in pixels is easily computed as the source's original dimensions multiplied by the scale. Or in other words

```
p = d × s
```

where p=pixel dimensions required, d=source dimensions, s=scale.

So to set the scale so that it takes a given source and makes it conform to a desired dimensions:

```
s = p / d
```

In an expression on the scale property you'd use

```
var p = [123, 456]; / desired output dimension
[ p[0] / width, p[1] / height ] * 100; // the *100 is because scale is a percentage
```

To be really fancy you could repurpose the scale value input so that it controlled the pixel dimensions. This means if you want the layer's dimension to be [123,456] you'd just dial it in in the scale control:

```
var d = value; //returns the pre-expression value of the property
[ p[0] / width, p[1] / height ] * 100
```